# Pause/resume feature in MediaRecorder

Tags: android, mediarecorder

I found many questions regarding the missing pause/resume feature in the MediaRecorder class. But then I saw the Camera app in Samsung galaxy S GT-i9000. It provides the feature to pause/resume video recording.

Does anybody have an idea, how they have implemented that ?

Comment: That function exists in Android 4.1.2 but is gone since Android 4.2 (on my sg2). Which is pretty sad IMHO.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, they are using non-public API's in the opencore.